# Twilio Studio and Rebrandly link shortener - Return parsed rather than string

Tags: php, json, twilio, twilio-studio

I adapted some instructions in order to Twilio Studio to obtain a shortened URL via a function which talks to the Rebrandly API. It works fine except the data returned is in a string rather than parsed, as can be seen here:

[image: Studio Log]

The code provided by Rebrandly is:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let response = { get_started: true };

let request = require("request");
let linkRequest = {
  destination: "https://www.carecalls.co.uk/conferma-ricevuta?num=" + event.receiver,
  domain: { fullName: "link.carecalls.co.uk" }
  //, slashtag: "A_NEW_SLASHTAG"
  //, title: ""
}

let requestHeaders = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "apikey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "workspace": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

request({
    uri: "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(linkRequest),
    headers: requestHeaders
}, (err, response, body) => {
  let link = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(`Long URL was ${link.destination}, short URL is ${link.shortUrl}`);
  callback(null, response);
});
};
```

What do I need to change in order to get a parsed list that studio can use to populate variables? I'm a pretty green developer so hoping this is obvious to someone! Help much appreciated

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Yes, the `body` in what you have shown appears to be a string of JSON, but if you decoded that using `JSON.parse(body)`, then it should not be a string any more. If you don’t know what the structure of the resulting object is - then log it to console, and inspect it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the function you supplied, you are returning the entire response object back to Twilio. The object is JSON stringified, but since the body of the response was already JSON, it has been double escaped. Studio will parse the response, but this will only parse the body once instead of the twice it would need.

Instead of returning the entire response, I would suggest just returning the body of the response. You already parsed the body to a variable `link`, so just return that variable to the `callback` function instead:

```js
  }, (err, response, body) => {
    let link = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(`Long URL was ${link.destination}, short URL is ${link.shortUrl}`);
    callback(null, link); // << return link here
  });
};
```

Doing this will give you that parsed response body that you want to be using.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the Callback, response is what is returned to Studio. If the response is an object, Twilio Functions will stringify it for you and send it back to Studio for parsing.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-function

> Callback Function
> When you have finished processing your request, you
> need to invoke the callback function to emit a response and complete
> execution. The callback method will automatically determine the data
> type of your response and serialize the output appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alan :)